# Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type

Tags: vb.net, shell32.dll

I have the following issue with my code.

```
Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type
```

The line of codes are as follow:

**SHFILEINFO Declaration**

```
Private Structure SHFILEINFO
    Public hIcon As IntPtr            ' : iconc
    Public iIcon As Integer           ' : icondex
    Public dwAttributes As Integer    ' : SFGAO_ flags
     _
    Public szDisplayName As String
     _
    Public szTypeName As String
End Structure
```

**SHGetFileInfo Declaration**

```
Private Declare Auto Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32.dll" _
        (ByVal pszPath As String, _
         ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer, _
         ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, _
         ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer, _
         ByVal uFlags As Integer) As IntPtr

Private Const SHGFI_ICON = &H100
Private Const SHGFI_SMALLICON = &H1
Private Const SHGFI_LARGEICON = &H0    ' Large icon
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
```

**SHGetFileInfo Usage**

```
Private Sub AddImageToImageListBox(ByVal strFileName As String)
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim shInfo As SHFILEINFO
    shInfo = New SHFILEINFO()

    shInfo.szDisplayName = New String(vbNullChar, MAX_PATH)
    shInfo.szTypeName = New String(vbNullChar, 80)

    Dim hIcon As IntPtr
    hIcon = SHGetFileInfo(strFileName, 0, shInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(shInfo), SHGFI_ICON Or SHGFI_SMALLICON)

    Dim MyIcon As Drawing.Bitmap
    MyIcon = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shInfo.hIcon).ToBitmap
    imgAttachment.AddImage(MyIcon)
    ilstAttachments.Items.Add(strFileName.ToString(), imgAttachment.Images.Count - 1)

    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    ErrMsg("AddImageToImageListBox (errHandler)")
End Sub
```

**Runtime**

Here are the values that being passed into SHGetFileInfo.

```
strFileName = "Copy (223) of Uncollected Card - Multiple Pages.TIF"
shInfo.dwAttributes = 0
shInfo.hIcon = 0
shInfo.iIcon = 0
shInfo.szDisplayName = ""
shInfo.szTypeName = ""
```

**Error**

When the stated values above are being passed to SHGetFileInfo, it returns 0 value thus making hIcon = 0.

When it reaches

```
MyIcon = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shInfo.hIcon).ToBitmap
```

The following error occurred

```
Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type
```

Can you guys help me to identify what is the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `SHFILEINFO` and `SHGetFileInfo` to this

```
   Private Structure SHFILEINFO
        Public hIcon As IntPtr            ' : iconc
        Public iIcon As Integer           ' : icondex
        Public dwAttributes As Integer    ' : SFGAO_ flags
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
        Public szDisplayName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=80)>
        Public szTypeName As String
    End Structure

    Private Declare Ansi Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal pszPath As String, _
        ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer, _
        ByVal uFlags As Integer) As IntPtr
```

Also, I would lose the `On Error Goto` and use a `Try/Catch`.

Comment: I have tried using your code but the same error still appeared. Regarding the On Error GoTo, I can't use Try/Catch method as we used custom MessageBox to display the error and the location.

Comment: Really? I have copied your code and replace mine but the same issue occurred on my site. Thanks BTW.

Comment: Did you try a different .tif or maybe an .ico?

Comment: I have tried different .tif and also hardcoded the file location path but same issue still appeared. I'm clueless at the moment.

Comment: @Naim - I was able to reproduce the error you are getting by passing in a filename that does not exist.  I would double check where your file is.